# Error: Invalid field Address for SObject Account

Tags: apex, visualforce

I have error syntax but i dont find the error.
the apex page, i want use the controller "Account"

```
 <apex:page standardController="Account">
<head>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyBjHETKBAuSy2JcXUdg6itU3nYFze4W_eU"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
var myOptions={ zoom: 15,mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,mapTypeControl: false };
var map;
var marker;
var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
var address ="{!Account.Address},{!Account.City}, {!Account.State}, {!Account.Zip_Code}";
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
content: "<b>{!Account.Name}</b><br>{!Account.Address}</br><br>{!Account.City}</br><br>{Account.State}</br><br>{!Account.Zip_Code}</br>"
});

geocoder.geocode( { address: address}, function(results, status) {
if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK&&results.length) {
if (status != google.maps.GeocoderStatus.ZERO_RESULTS) {

//create map
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), myOptions);

//center map
map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);

//create marker
marker = new google.maps.Marker({
position: results[0].geometry.location,
map: map,
title: "{!Account.Name}"
});

//add listeners
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
infowindow.open(map,marker);
});
google.maps.event.addListener(infowindow, 'closeclick', function() {
map.setCenter(marker.getPosition());
});
}
} else {
$('#map').css({'height' : '15px'});
$('#map').html("Oops! {!Account.Name}'s billing address could not be found, please make sure the address is correct.");
resizeIframe();
}
});

function resizeIframe() {
var me = window.name;
if (me) {
var iframes = parent.document.getElementsByName(me);
if (iframes&&iframes.length == 1) {
height = document.body.offsetHeight;
iframes[0].style.height = height + "px";
}
}
}
});
</script>
<style>
#map {
font-family: Arial;
font-size:12px;
line-height:normal !important;
height:250px;
background:transparent;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="map"></div>
</body>
</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is **no** *Address* field on an `Account` object. The address fields available are *BillingAddress* and *ShippingAddress* and they are [compound fields](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/compound_fields_address.htm).

You will need to provide either the compound field name or individual fields as required from the required address. E.g., a query to retrieve these fields will look like as:

```
SELECT Name, BillingAddress FROM Account
```

OR

```
SELECT Name, BillingCity, BillingStreet FROM Account
```

For API Names of these fields, refer to the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfFieldRef.meta/sfFieldRef/salesforce_field_reference_Account.htm) and [accessing compound fields](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/compound_fields_address.htm).

Comment: "Address fields are provided on many standard objects, such as Account, Contact, Quote, and User. Some objects provide fields for multiple addresses. For example, Account provides for four different addresses. In this case, address field names are prefixed with the type of address, for example, BillingAddress, ShippingAddress, and so on." but i find not a example in the documentation...

Comment: Scroll down a bit further in the documentation for compound fields and you’ll find the example. I have updated the answer to reflect that too.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be trying to use standard fields on a standard object.

“__c” indicates a custom field. Remove those.

Comment: Yes i edited the code now but i have new error Error: Invalid field Address for SObject Account